# How to use flatlist with scrolltoIndex and refreshcontrol together and only scrolling on mount / not when refreshing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use a Flatlist and when navigating to screen, scroll to the ID I get from params (using scrolltoIndex).

I also have a pull to refresh enabled (using RefreshControl) in Flatlist. The problem is that when I refresh, the screen scrolls again to the item which I don't want.

I only want to scroll to item on mount and when refreshing I want to stay on top of the screen. How can I achieve that?

I cannot pass RefreshControll to a parent of the flatlist such as a ScrollView because you cant have a Flatlist inside a ScrollView and if I pass it to another Flatlist wrapping my Flatlist with the scrolltoIndex function, then the scroll doesnt work.

```
const Screen = ({route}) => {
    const {id, reportId} = route.params;
    let flatListRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (flatListRef && data.length > 0) {
            const index = data.findIndex(item => {
                return item._id === id
            });
            if (id && index !== -1) {
                flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
                    animated: true,
                    index: index,
                    viewPosition: 0.5
                });
            }
        }

    }, [data, id]);
    return (
        <FlatList
            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh}/>
            }
            data={data}
            ref={ref => {
                flatListRef = ref;
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
            renderItem={({item}, i) => {})
                >
                </FlatList>
    )
}
```

Comment: I added code now, didnt add before as its not really relevant to the understanding of the question as I believe.

Comment: Did ```onRefresh``` call ```setData``` ?